# Github Gitignor is not working with OneSignalSDKWorker

Tags: laravel, github, nuxt.js, onesignal

nuxt onesignal package is generate OneSignalSDKWorker every time `npm run dev`

```
 client/static/OneSignalSDKWorker.js
```

every time i push to server its says conflicts

i tried to add this file to `.gitignore`

```
static/OneSignalSDKWorker.*
```

still not ignoring and make project conflicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> still not ignoring

It would only if, after updating the .gitignore, you also remove those files from Git:

```
git rm --cached static/OneSignalSDKWorker.*
git commit -m "Do not track static files"
```

Then check those same files are indeed ignored:

```
git check-ignore -v -- static/OneSignalSDKWorker.js
```

If the check-ignore returns nothing, then the file is *not* ignored and can be tracked again.
What you want to see is a `.gitignore` rule from that command.

Comment: it reply me on check-ignore `$ git check-ignore -v -- client/static/OneSignalSDKWorker.js
client/.gitignore:93:OneSignalSDKWorker.*       client/static/OneSignalSDKWorker.js` is this fine?

Comment: @sidheart Yes, that is indeed what you want to see.